# tensorflow: run same metrics multiple times with different input

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I want to save prediction and recall to tensorboard every 100 iterations during training, and I need to compute the metrics for both training and test dataset. Here is the code that I use:

```
precision, _ = tf.metrics.precision(labels_placeholder, mypredictions, 
metrics_collections = ['metrics'], updates_collections = ['update_op'])

tf.summary.scalar('train_precision', precision, collections = ['train_metrics'])
tf.summary.scalar('test_precision', precision, collections = ['test_metrics'])

 # the metrics ops have local variables that need to be
 # init'd each time.
 sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())            
 for batch in range(100):
     train_images, train_labels = train_dataset.next_batch()
     feed_dict = {images_placeholder: train_images, labels_placeholder: train_labels}
     sess.run(tf.get_collection('update_op'), feed_dict = feed_dict)

 sess.run(tf.get_collection('metrics'), feed_dict = feed_dict)        
 summary_str = sess.run(train_metrics_summary, feed_dict=feed_dict)
 summary_writer.add_summary(summary_str, global_step_val)

 sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())            
 for batch in range(100):
     test_images, test_labels = test_dataset.next_batch()
     feed_dict = {images_placeholder: test_images, labels_placeholder: test_labels}
     sess.run(tf.get_collection('update_op'), feed_dict = feed_dict)

 sess.run(tf.get_collection('metrics'), feed_dict = feed_dict)
 summary_str = sess.run(test_metrics_summary, feed_dict=feed_dict)
 summary_writer.add_summary(summary_str, global_step_val)
```

Note that to run and get the summary of same variables on both train and test data, I define two summary ops for training and testing, put them in different collections, and run the two summary ops separately for train and test data.

I also think I should re-initialize the local variables for the update_op, because the [official doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/sensitivity_at_specificity) says

> It sets the sum and count variables to zero.

My question: is this the best way to run ops on both train and test set?

The TF document also mentioned that

> Note that when evaluating the same metric multiple times on different inputs, one must specify the scope of each metric to avoid accumulating the results together:

```
labels = ...
predictions0 = ...
predictions1 = ...

accuracy0 = tf.contrib.metrics.accuracy(labels, predictions0, name='preds0')
accuracy1 = tf.contrib.metrics.accuracy(labels, predictions1, name='preds1')
```

But that seems a different approach with mine, becuase I just define a single variable `precision` with just one `myprediction` variable. And it seems I don't need to worry about this issue and don't need to add `name` option?

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing to remember when using `tf.metrics` functions is that all meetrics here are running metrics, calculating running metrics over multiple runs. For details, see this article: http://ronny.rest/blog/post_2017_09_11_tf_metrics/
So here you are calculating cumulative precision over both training and testing data, because update_op for precision is the same for both of them and both datasets, training and testing, are updating same running precision.